# How do I Convert Textbox to decimal

Tags: c#, string, textbox, decimal

I want to convert a code in datagrid textbox to decimal but don't just know how to. I have search the net and this forum but not exactly whai I want. Any help would be appreciated Below is the code:

```cs
public void LoadStock() {
  int i = 0;
  dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
  cn.Open();
  cm = new SqlCommand("select * from vwStockIn where RefNo like '" + txtRefNo.Text + "' and Status like 'Pending' ", cn);
  dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
  while (dr.Read()) {
    i++;
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(i, dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString(), dr[5].ToString(), dr[6].ToString(), dr[7].ToString(), dr["CompanyName"].ToString(), dr["AccBalance"].ToString());
  }
  dr.Close();
  cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Side note: It is hard to believe you searched on SO and found recommendation to construct SQL query with string concatenation... One may think that this is an indication of the author actually misrepresenting amount of research they did - that's why following [MCVE] guidelines of posting code is useful.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain what do *you* mean "decimal" (which is probably not `decimal` type) and what behavior you are currently getting from code shown in the post as well as expected results.

Comment: Also, please use sql parameters rather than concatenating strings. You're open to sql injection.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "how to convert a string to decimal c#"?

Answer (score 0):

To covert the text in the texbox to a decimal first you have to check if the text in the text box is a number. For that you can just...

```cs
bool isNumeric = float.TryParse(YourTextBox.Text, out float n);
```

After this, "n" will hold the value of the decimal, but **optionally** you can just...

```cs
if (isNumeric)
{
    Nullable<Double> yourNewNum = Convert.ToDouble(YourTextBox.Text);
} 
else 
{
    // Your else code here.
}
```

Comment: If `TryParse` succeeds, then `n` will hold the parsed value. No need for a call to `Convert.ToDouble`

Comment: Yes it's numeric and it's among other fields in a row - datagrid. I inserted the exact code above for a guide when responding

Answer (score 0):

You can just parse it into decimal:

```
decimal.Parse(your_string_variable);
```

Comment: I tried your answer and it is giving the same error as "input string was not in a correct format "